# How can I let the file date be formatted according to ISO 8601 also in load/store dialogues

Tags: gtk, qt, time, date

I am using Xubuntu 22.04. I have added a line

`alias date='date -Iseconds'`

to `/etc/bash.bashrc` in order to let file dates be formatted according to ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss)

Further I have selected the format YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss for Thunar.

In file open close dialogs, I still encounter this awful today/yesterday/... format. **I want to see ISO 8601 dates in all file open/store dialogs.**

**How can I achieve this?**

Since the file date always has the same length and the file size is also a short thing, I arrange the columns with change date and size before file name, followed by owner:group, access rights. The file names can vary in length, with the "name first" arrangement the other columns often get out of view. I often have to sort things either by change date, size or file name. With the default order change date and size often are placed too the right to be visible. With my preferred arrangements I can at least see the beginnings of the file names.

**Would it be possible, to let the columns be arranged accordingly in all programs?**

I know, several flavours of Qt and of GTK are called by different application programs for the load store dialogs. I guess, each framework can be configured in this regard. Hopefully there is one tool, which sets them all to the same configuration in parallel. If not: **Where are those places for the different flavours of Qt and of GTK, to let them show dates in ISO 8601 format?** I neither care for the T between date and time, nor for the colons as separators in the time part. Colons are not a good separator there because another widespread operating system does not allow this character in file names. But that's another story.